# Yield on recursive data structure

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a generator with a Python class that works somewhat similarly to a linked list.

Here is a really simple example of what I mean:

```
class GeneratorTest():
    def __init__(self, list):
        if list:
            self.elem = list[0]
            if list[1:]:
                self.n = GeneratorTest(list[1:])
            else:
                self.n = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        my_next = self
        while my_next is not None:
            yield my_next
            my_next = my_next.n
```

Of course this is just an example, but it's enough to illustrate the point.

Now, I was expecting to be able to invoke something like:

```
g = GeneratorTest([1,2,3,4,5])
for x in g:
    print x
```

And have the cycle stop when it reached the last value, but the for loop just continues endlessly.

I'm quite new to generators, so I'm sure it's a basic premise I'm missing here.

Is the problem related to the fact that I yield the same object that creates the generator?
I'm sure that if I had an object with a list of GeneratorTest objects, I could return each of these objects quite simply, but I feel as there should be a way to make this work without a "wrapper" object.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `list` is the name of a builtin, so you are shadowing it when you use it as an argument to your `__init__` method.

Comment: yes, yes, I know, this is just an example I hacked up and didn't bother with the names. The real code is similar in logic but with names that make sense and don't overshadow builtins. Thanks for pointing that out anyway!

Comment: It's most helpful to provide good examples: self contained and demonstrative.

Comment: my_next = my_next.n    never runs, since it follows the yield, right?

Comment: No, that's not the problem. If the next() was actually called as I believed it would, the generator would "save" the context of the execution, and on the next iteration would continue *from* the yield, thus moving the state forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `next` (or, in Py3, `__next__`) shouldn't be a generator - it should maintain its state externally, and `return` each value. Yours keeps returning a new generator each time, but since Python doesn't iterate over *that* generator, your loop never actually runs. 
This may mean you want `__iter__` to return something other than `self` initially (although whatever it returns is required to have an `__iter__` that returns self).

But the good news is that generators exist precisely to keep track of these rules for you. Move your current `next` code into `__iter__` and everything works - Python *does* iterate over whatever `__iter__` returns (as you would expect).

Comment: Indeed it does! That makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

I did essentially this when I ported a treap datastructure from java; this code may serve as an example:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/

See also "yield from", a recent Python feature that makes this easier:
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/

The treap code does it without yield from.